# How to make sure the first of two workflows go first before the second?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow ( workflow A ) that creates an approval flow and another workflow ( Workflow B )that creates the Title name and other fields.

I would like to make sure Workflow B finishes first ( so that the Title name is created ) before Workflow A begins the approval and NOT having the title show up as "No Title"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Workflow A` try to add a **wait for** action at the top of your actions to wait until the field have a specific value

```
Wait for field to equal value
```

You can find `Wait for` action in actions list below `list action` as shown below

[image]

Because of the `wait for` must have a specific value, you can create a field in your list that holds a specific value to be updated with the end of your workflow B.

**For example:** create `workflowBstatus` field that will be updated at the last action in your `workflow B` with the value `"Finished"`, then in `workflow A` wait for this column value become `"Finished"`

Comment: You are welcome @MikeRooker :)